# Use web3.js to retrieve all storage from a smart contract

Tags: web3js, storage

I try to reverse engineer a smart contract on ethereum. Now I want to retrieve all used/changed storage from a contract via web3. Is this possible?
I understand, that I cannot get keys to e.g. mappings, since they are used only in hashed form (like function names), but I think it should be possible to get all storage which was changed since the contract exists. But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have access to the source code you can see the storage layout and figure out all the storage locations for a contract's variables. You can retrieve the values at these locations using web3.js or ethers.js getStorageAt.

here are some links that show accessing contract storage with web3/ethers
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9C4zgskHwg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg6nt3YW74o
https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/accessing-private-data/

otherwise, you could go through all the transactions associated with a contract and figure out what changes have been made.

You can see some data in storage slots and changes from transactions of that with etherscan.io

here's completely random example
[https://etherscan.io/tx/0x98c6b4488501e6b932de4dccbf399736976810e4608baf79dbe5df68629a5832#statechange][1]

expand the state change area, you can see how the transaction changed the values at storage slots 0 and 10 and two other storage addresses designated with 32byte hashes. You can find a contract's deployment transaction to view the changes at deployment.
Within the state change area you can change the view of the bytes32 data from hex to number / text / address as a quick way to see if it makes sense as another datatype

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please provide an example of etherscan showing changes? Then I'll mark your answer as solved.

Comment: ok. I've added a bit as requested